# Enterprise Architect: C# Optional parameters?

Tags: c#, code-generation, optional-parameters, enterprise-architect

Any option to get Enterprise Architect to recognize optional parameters in C#?

I have attempted to import existing code and get the following error:

> There was an error parsing
>   C:\MyProject\FooBar.cs on line 30. 
>   Unexpected symbol: =

**Code:**

```
public void Foo(int bar = 1) //Line 30
{
}
```

I have also attempted to start from scratch and generate code from Enterprise Architect. I created a class, then added an operation to that class and defined the parameters. The form for editing parameters allows me to supply the "Name", "Type", and "Default" (as well as other information). I added Name: bar, Type: int, Default: 1. Then when I generated the code this is what I get (no optional parameter generated!)

```
namespace System {
    public class FooBar {

        /// 
        /// <param name="bar"></param>
        public void Foo(int bar){

        }

    }//end FooBar

}//end namespace System
```

---

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?  Is it in the error window, produced from compiler, some other tool, etc ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sparx has just released [version 9](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/9/index.html) of EA, which has support for C# 4.0.

Comment: Wow, literally it came out today!

Answer (score 2):

Optional parameters are supported from C# 4.0 and up. If you are using an older version then using them will simply not work and result in the error you are mentioning.